# C Programming for perfect squares

Tags: c

I cannot figure out how to get a number from the user then turn out an output to state all the possible perfect squares up till the program reaches the given number.

We are using Loops in C and we have to use a for loop to take the number and output the possible perfect squares.

Here is an example of what the output should be:
Enter a number between 1 and 1000 inclusive: -50
The number you entered, -50, was not between 1 and 1000.
Please re-enter a number between 1 and 1000 inclusive: 100

The perfect squares between 1 and 100 inclusive are:
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100

My code:

```
int main(void)
{
    // Constant and Variable Declarations
    const int MIN_NUM = 1; // constant for the minNum allowed
    const int MAX_NUM = 1000; // constant for the maxNum allowed
    int userNum = 0; // input variable
    int userNum1 = userNum;
    int perfectSquare = 0;


    // *** Your program goes here ***
    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 1000 inclusive: "); // asking the user to input their number
    scanf("%d", &userNum);

    // validation
    while (userNum < MIN_NUM || userNum > MAX_NUM) {
        printf("   The number you entered, %d, was not between 1 and 1000.\n", userNum); // telling user num they entered was not valid
        printf("   Please re-enter a number between 1 and 1000 inclusive: "); // asking the user to enter a different number
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
    }
    printf("\n"); // blank line

    // output
    printf("The perfect squares between 1 and 100 inclusive are:");

    


    printf("\n");
    return 0;
} // end main()
```

not sure how to find the perfect sqaures
Sorry if any of this is unclear this is my first time posting on overflow! Thanks for all the help

Comment: whats the question, your code works fine. I mean it does nothing with squares etc but it prompts and reprompts correctly

Comment: Could you do it without a computer? That is, tell me the square numbers not bigger than 25, or not bigger than 150.

Comment: Oh I see, you want us to tell you how to get the perfect squares up x. OK, loop from 1 upwards squaring until the square is > the user entered number

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is, instead of checking which numbers less than `userNum` are perfect squares, print each perfect square starting from 1 until you find one that is more than `userNum`. This can easily be done with a for loop.

(the code itself is left as an exercise for the reader)

Comment: I would say 'generate each perfect..' not 'print'

Comment: Welp, that would certainly have left even more as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I think I have done what you said but I keep getting an IL of 0s

Answer (score -1):

Thank you guys for the help!

```
int main(void)
{
    // Constant and Variable Declarations
    const int MIN_NUM = 1; // constant for the minNum allowed
    const int MAX_NUM = 1000; // constant for the maxNum allowed
    int userNum = 0; // input variable
    int userNum1 = userNum;
    int perfectSquare = 0;
    int root1 = 0;
    int root2 = 0;


    // *** Your program goes here ***
    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 1000 inclusive: "); // asking the user to input their number
    scanf("%d", &userNum);

    // validation
    while (userNum < MIN_NUM || userNum > MAX_NUM) {
        printf("   The number you entered, %d, was not between 1 and 1000.\n", userNum); // telling user num they entered was not valid
        printf("   Please re-enter a number between 1 and 1000 inclusive: "); // asking the user to enter a different number
        scanf("%d", &userNum);
    }
    printf("\n"); // blank line

    // output
    printf("The perfect squares between %d and %d inclusive are:\n", MIN_NUM, userNum);
    
    for (int i = 1; perfectSquare <= userNum - 1; i++) {
        root1 = sqrt(floor(userNum));   
        root2 = sqrt(userNum);
        perfectSquare = i * i;
        printf("%d\n", perfectSquare);
        if (perfectSquare > userNum) {
            break;
        }
    }



    printf("\n");
    return 0;
} // end main()
```

output:

```
Enter a number between 1 and 1000 inclusive: 81

The perfect squares between 1 and 81 inclusive are:
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).